# lately, I am try to build a client and server to send and receive message and I am stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am just trying to build a basic chat with one client and server. When I run both program they both gave me same error. This error is of client1.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Abishek/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/client1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
  File "C:\Users\Abishek\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.2\scratches\socket.py", line 64, in <module>
    IntEnum._convert_(
  File "C:\Python37\Lib\enum.py", line 349, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: _convert_
```

and chatserver.py throw an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Abishek/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/chatserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from  socket import AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, socket
  File "C:\Users\Abishek\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.2\scratches\socket.py", line 64, in <module>
    IntEnum._convert_(
  File "C:\Python37\Lib\enum.py", line 349, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: _convert_
```

and my code for client1.py is

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
import threading

FORMAT = 'utf-8'
server =input('Enter server ip :')
port = 8080
DISCONNECT_MSG = 'break' or 'disconnect'
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)


def connection(server,port):
    try:
        sock.connect((server, port))
        print("Connection successful")
    except Exception as err:
        print('Connection failed :' +str(err))


def send_msg(client_name):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        message = input('>>> ')
        msg = message.encode(FORMAT)
        client_info_with_msg = f'[{client_name}: {message}]'
        sock.send(client_info_with_msg.encode())
        if message == DISCONNECT_MSG:
            print(f'{client_name} DISCONNECTED!!')
            connected = False


def recv_msg():
    run = True
    while run:
        recv_message = sock.recv(512)
        message = recv_message.decode('utf-8')
        if message == DISCONNECT_MSG:
            run = False
        print(f'{message}')


def main(server,port):
    connection(server, port)
    client_name = input("Enter your name: ")
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=send_msg, args=client_name)
    thread1.start()
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=recv_msg, args=None)
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    sock.close()

main(server,port)
```

And chatserver.py is:

```
from  socket import AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, socket
import threading

SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 4444
sock = socket.socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
format = 'utf-8'
buffer_size = 128
ADDR = (SERVER,port)
Disconnect_msg = 'Disconnected'


def connection(SERVER,port):
    sock.bind(ADDR)
    run = True
    try:
        sock.connect(ADDR)
        print('Connection successful')
    except Exception as err:
        print('Error connecting to client :'+str(err))
        run = False


def receiving_data(conn, addr):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        recv_msg = conn.recv(buffer_size).decode(format)
        if recv_msg:
            print(f"[MESSAGE RECEIVED FROM {conn}  {addr}] : {recv_msg}")
        if Disconnect_msg in recv_msg:
            print(f"[CLIENT {conn}  { addr} Disconnected]")
            connected= False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock.bind(ADDR)
    sock.listen(5)
    print(f'Server ip; {SERVER}')
    print('Waiting for connection...')
    conn , addr = sock.accept()
    accpt_conn = threading.Thread(target=connection, args=ADDR)
    recv_data = threading.Thread(target=receiving_data, args =(conn,addr))
    recv_data.start()
    accpt_conn.start()
    recv_data.join()
    accpt_conn.join()
    sock.close()
```

Can you please help me what I am doing wrong here.
And I am using Pycharm as my IDE and I am on windows 10.

Thank you everyone...

Comment: Did you try running it directly in powershell?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatserver.py", line 4, in <module>
    SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostbyname' ` but client1.py ran but server didnot. When i ran in command prompt

Comment: Remember sockets are a unix thing, not everything is going to work in windows, and I'm a little surprised it works in windows at all.

Comment: I think it's pycharm that's causing problem, Thank you so much . Running in powershell looks pretty good. So it should work now

Comment: Glad you got it running. Good luck!

Comment: `gethostname` and `gethostbyname` are members of `socket`, not of `socket.socket`, which is what you get with `from socket import socket`. At least in Windows. Maybe that caused the problem.